# Headphone Pulse Audio bluetooth - Microphone does not work

Tags: pulseaudio, headphones, microphone

I've been researching and seems like there's no solution for this issue, I've tried with and without using **Blueman**, I tried a couple of solutions found in other **Ask Ubuntu** questions. Unfortunately, none of the solutions work.

**Ubuntu:** 16.04

**Device:** Headphone Bluetooth Pulse PH150

**Pulseaudio: 8.0**

It doesn't work with Bluetooth nor cable, any idea?

Comment: The microphone does not work with A2DP (HiFi audio) profile.

Comment: but I'm using the other one